# How to draw three stack digrams with arrows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am trying to draw the below digram:

[image]

Till now I am able to do this much:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,fill=LightSteelBlue!60,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm] (a) at (2,0) {(2,3)};
\node[draw,fill=LightSteelBlue!60,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm] (b) at (2,1) {(2,4)};
\node[draw,fill=LightSteelBlue!60,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm] (a) at (2,2) {(4,2)};
\node[draw,fill=LightSteelBlue!60,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm] (a) at (2,3) {(2,5)};
\node[draw,fill=LightSteelBlue!60,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm] (a) at (2,4) {(6,2)};
\node[draw,fill=LightSteelBlue!60,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm] (a) at (2,5) {(6,4)};
\node[draw,fill=LightSteelBlue!60,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm] (a) at (2,6) {(7,2)};
\node[draw,fill=LightSteelBlue!60,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm] (a) at (8,3) {(2,3)};
\node[draw,fill=LightSteelBlue!60,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm] (b) at (8,4) {(2,4)};
\node[draw,fill=LightSteelBlue!60,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm] (a) at (8,5) {(4,2)};
\node[draw,fill=LightSteelBlue!60,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm] (a) at (8,6) {(2,5)};
\node[draw,fill=Red!60,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm] (a) at (14,3) {(2,3)};
\node[draw,fill=Red!60,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm] (b) at (14,4) {(2,4)};
\node[draw,fill=Red!60,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm] (a) at (14,5) {(4,2)};
\node[draw,fill=Red!60,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm] (a) at (14,6) {(2,5)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Giving me output: 
[image]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a brace decoration for the brace and make extra nodes for the label. You can also reduce the redundancies in your code a lot by an appropriate use of `\foreach`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={brace,amplitude=2mm,mirror},]
\foreach[count=\i] \x/\y in {7/2,6/4,6/2,2/5,4/2,2/4,2/3}
    \node[draw,fill=LightSteelBlue!60,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm,below] (a) at (2,-\i) {(\x,\y)};

\foreach[count=\i] \x/\y in {2/5,4/2,2/4,2/3}{
    \node[draw,fill=LightSteelBlue!60,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm,below] (b) at (8,-\i) {(\x,\y)};
    \node[draw,fill=Red!60,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm,below] (c) at (14,-\i) {(\x,\y)};
}
\draw [decorate] (0.3,-1) --node[left=3mm]{$S_1$} (0.3,-3);
\draw [decorate] (0.3,-4) --node[left=3mm]{$S_2$} (0.3,-6);

\node[align=center,below] at (2,-9) (alabel) {$S$\\ explicit};
\node[align=center,below] at (8,-6) (blabel) {$S'$\\ used};
\node[align=center,below] at (14,-6) (clabel) {$T$};

\draw[->]
    (a) edge (alabel)
    (b) edge (blabel)
    (c) edge (clabel)
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```